# How to jump between headings (like h3) with keyboard in NVDA?

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility, html-heading, nvda

**I know that the good scenario is, when I click on number <kbd>3</kbd> on my keyboard I'm supposed to jump between my `h3` headers.**

For some reason this thing didn't happen in my case and my screen reader (NVDA) didn't show me any indication of it.

It's some list of results and on each result the title is `h3`.

Here is one example for one result:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGkjdQ

Comment: Anyone??? it's very important to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following page : [Keyboard Shortcuts for NVDA](http://webaim.org/resources/shortcuts/nvda)

`Numpad 3` and `3` keys have different use.

- Numpad 3 : "Say Next Character"
- 1-6: "Headings level 1-6"

So you must not use the numpad when you want to navigate through the headings.

Comment: It does not work for me on both ways.
Is it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Questions that would be helpful in debugging this:

1. Are you in *browse mode* or *focus mode*?
2. Are you pressing the **3** on the keyboard or the number pad?
3. Are you at the end of the page?
4. Does NVDA speak to you ("No next heading 3") or make any noise when you press the **3** key?
5. Do you have an example that shows the HTML output, not your uncompiled Angular?

If in browse mode ([source](http://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#toc41)):

> While in browse mode, For quicker navigation, NVDA also provides single character keys to jump to certain fields in the document. Note that not all of these commands are supported in every type of document.
>
> The following keys by themselves jump to the next available element, while adding the shift key causes them to jump to the previous element:
>
> - h: heading
> - […]
> - 1 to 6: headings at levels 1 to 6 respectively

If you are not sure which mode you are in, you can toggle between them by pressing the **NVDA** key + **Space** ([source](http://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#BrowseMode)).

The NVDA key changes based on whether you are using a laptop or desktop computer, and you can also override it. If on a desktop computer, then it is typically the **Insert** key on the number pad. If on a laptop then it is typically the **Caps Lock** key. ([source](http://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#toc19))

Comment: First of all, thank very much for your detailed answer.

Comment: And now for your questions:
1. I'm try both modes the same actions.
2. i"m pressing the 3 on the keyboard.
3. I'm not at the end of the page.
4. Yes, it speak to me and I'm using the "Speech Viewer" and it write and say: "No next heading 3".
5. I;m sorry but I dont have any other example beside what I already share here.

Do you have any other ideas why this might happen?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first time I pressing number 3 it say "heading  clickable  level 3", and it even jump to the area where my list items with all h3 are,  but when I pressing again on number 3 it start say "No next heading 3".

Comment: If NVDA says "no next heading," then what does it say when you press **Shift** + **3**? Also, if NVDA says "clickable level 3" then that suggests you have a _tabindex_ or other attribute on the heading that might be jacking it up, such as a _role_ attribute. Use the browser inspector to pull the rendered HTML and amend your question so we can see the code.

Comment: 1. After I pressing 3 number for the first time and then another time, now when I press Shift + 3 its say "no next heading", even tho before he did recognize the first h3.
2. No, there isn't any tabindex or roll attribute on the "h3".
Only  "ng-repeat", "class", ng-if.

Answer (score 0):

Both NVDA and JAWS show the h3 in the headings dialog.  I'm able to navigate to it using the 3 key along the top row of number keys (not number pad).

NVDA screenshot:

[image: nvda]

JAWS screenshot:

[image: jaws]